# How can I run a script as administrator inside a Windows container

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to install the [Windows Enterprise WDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/installing-the-enterprise-wdk) on a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image based on [windowsservercore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184075.aspx). The application installs by unziping and I have already done that and committed that image to Docker. Now I need to run a script that sets environment variables. According to the Enterprise WDK install instructions I must run this script as administrator. I've done this directly on my desktop machine and it works file. Within the Docker Container, the default login user is

```
PS C:\> whoami
user manager\containeradministrator
```

I've tried enabling the admin account.

```
PS C:\> net user administrator /active:yes
The command completed successfully.
PS C:\> net user administrator Pa$$w0rd
The command completed successfully.
```

I try to start a shell as administrator, but the user does not change.

```
PS C:\> runas /user:administrator powershell
Enter the password for administrator:
Attempting to start powershell as user "C597C386289A\administrator" ...
PS C:\> whoami
user manager\containeradministrator
```

And if I run my script it fails to have set any of the environment values specified in the script.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: You might have an issue with [UAC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server_core/2009/01/19/user-account-control-uac-and-server-core/), could you temporarily disable it? Runas as you wrote it does not allow opening an elevated command prompt, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows). I'd give NirCmd a try :-)

Comment: How are you connecting to the container? RDP? Remote powershell?

Comment: @harrymc Running the container in interactive mode.

Comment: Because the local Administrator account is a very special account, a login might be required. Why can't you use another "normal" administrator account?

Comment: I would try to ask this question on a specialized docker forum, like https://forums.docker.com/c/docker-for-windows.

Comment: @smilev I may be using it wrong. Running nircmd:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -it daniel/core nircmd elevatecmd runassystem powershell
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 28403ea18a9c413f8bbb9af97
57c877e3c7e8bba6faea518149bfddc719d667a encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The operation timed out because a response was not received from the Virtual Machine hosting the Container. (0xc0370109).

Comment: *UAC is not available in Server Core, since it is a command line only interface*. You can safely skip all the recomendations about UAC here. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server_core/2009/01/19/user-account-control-uac-and-server-core/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not insufficient rights at all. See [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server_core/2009/01/19/user-account-control-uac-and-server-core/).

> **UAC is not available in Server Core, since it is a command line only
> interface**, doesn’t have IE, or support for user applications. In
> addition, to use UAC with the command prompt you need to have the
> Explorer Shell so that you can click Start, right click on Command
> Prompt, and select run as administrator, which obviously isn’t
> possible on Server Core.

You are already running commands as an administrator, otherwise commands like

`net user administrator Pa$$w0rd`

would fail inevitably.

Your problem is something else.

Windows Server Core is not supported for installing WDK.
About setting environment variables on Server Core see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/70603/update-environment-variables-from-the-command-line-windows-2008-server-core).

You should take a look at that script and what it actually does, if it uses SET or SETX commands or something else and there you can find a clue why the variables are not being set properly. It might be that they are set permanently but not in your current window.

Comment: I had replaced the `set` commands with `setx` trying to debug other problems. That's what led me down the path of trying to get real admin privilege.

Comment: your second link doesn't redirect to anything meaningful anymore